# Excel - bringing in a range of data to calculate proper breakage rates, AKA fun with sumproduct

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I'm working with a multi-step process to make a thing.

Things break at various stages in the process, and need to be started over from the start when that happens.

Each step of the process has a different breakage rate.

There's a "Rate Table" which bringing in different breakage rates for different steps in the process. For example:

```
Location ---- Step ---- Rate
    A           1        10%
    B           1        15%
    A           2        5%
    A           3         20%
```

So far, I have a fairly "Simple" Capacity*(1-Index-Match(BreakageRate)*(BreakageRateMultiplier)) to calculate what the breakage rate is on any given step, and how many units could be completed from the step.

So right now in Location A, Step 1, if my simple capacity was 1000 units, I'd take 1000*(1-.1) (We're ignoring the growth factor for now) = 900 units could be completed.

However, it can't quite do 900 completed units a day - more items will break further down the line, and those will also need to be recycled through. A simple viewpoint would be that 5% break on step 2, and 15% will break on step 3.

But it's not quite as simple as adding in the extra multipliers (1-Step1)(1-Step2)(1-Step3) - 15% of the items through step 3 also break, and of the numbers thrown back through, some of those will break AGAIN.

So my question is twofold - What's the correct mathematical modeling for this?

And what's a formula that can properly capture and bring in the next N steps of breakage? I'm hoping to find a formula that works regardless of the number of steps. (StepNumber>=@[Stepnumber] is probably involved at some point...)

Comment: Is this a maths question, or Excel question? (I do understand part of it is how to put the mathematical model into an Excel formula, but it seems you first are needing that model).  Your main issue seems to be perhaps better suited for [https://math.stackexchange.com/](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It's both. Even if we ignore the maths issue, I'm not sure how I'd multiply N breakage rates together

Comment: You have to question the data collection methodology to make sure the percentage is based on the total number of items that pass the previous step. Yes, it's a maths question. But even before that, you need to verify how those percentages were calculated --- or what the expectation is from the report audience. Make sure your Excel calculation matches both of those expectations.

Comment: Breakages are currently calculated on 1-UnitsLeft/UnitsEntered - in other words, they're calculated solely on that individual step basis